# How do I remove Maven Error Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging

Tags: java, maven

I've a project with having 3 modules, I work on Intellij with jdk 16. Problem is while doing MVN clean install, I stuck with the following error:

```
 The project org.springbank:user-management:1.0 (B:\spring\user-management\pom.xml) has 
  1 error [ERROR]     'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid. Aggregator projects 
  require 'pom' as packaging. @ line 4, column 109
```

Above error pointing out that parent pom.xml has a problem.

I also mention hereunder my all three pom.xml

pom.xml - Parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>org.springbank</groupId>
   <artifactId>user-management</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>

 <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>

<modules>
    <module>user.core</module>
    <module>user.cmd.api</module>
    <module>user.query.api</module>
</modules>

</project>
```

pom.xml user.core

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.springbank</groupId>
<artifactId>user.core</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>user.core</name>
<description>The User Core Project</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>16</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

pom.xml user.cmd.api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.springbank</groupId>
<artifactId>user.cmd.api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>user.cmd.api</name>
<description>User Command API Project</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>16</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parent `pom.xml`, you need to specify the packaging as being of tap `pom` since it default to `jar` while your parent descriptor is intended to aggregate sub-modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springbank</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-management</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging> <!-- set the packaging as pom -->

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>user.core</module>
        <module>user.cmd.api</module>
        <module>user.query.api</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Comment: I get now error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project user.cmd.api: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release. All modules status show as Success except user.cmd.api.

Comment: @TheKash looks like you have an jdk < 16 installed

Comment: @TheKash this should be a different issue and the main OP issue should be answered.
Don't hesitate to open and link a new issue :)

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid. Aggregator projects 
  require 'pom' as packaging. @ line 4, column 109
```

your parent pom should have packaging type `pom`

```
<groupId>org.springbank</groupId>
<artifactId>user-management</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```